# Uploadify: HTTP error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, uploadify

I know this was answered before but the solutions on the other posts are not working for me. I'm getting an HTTP Error (404) on the uploadify box when trying to upload.

This is my uploadify related code:
head:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/uploadify/uploadify.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/uploadify/jquery.uploadify-3.1.min.js"></script>
```

body:

```
<input type="file" name="file_upload" id="file_upload" />
```

document.ready:

```
$('#file_upload').uploadify({
                    'swf'      : 'js/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
                    'uploader' : 'js/uploadify/uploadify.php' ,
                    'cancelImg' : 'js/uploadify/cancel.png',
                    'multi'      : false,
                    'buttonText' : 'Add main picture'
                });
```

uploadify.php:

```
<?php
/*
Uploadify
Copyright (c) 2012 Reactive Apps, Ronnie Garcia
Released under the MIT License <http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php> 
*/

// Define a destination
$targetFolder = 'C:/xampp/htdocs/site/sites_images/'; // Relative to the root

if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    $tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
    $targetPath = $targetFolder;
    $targetFile = $targetFolder . $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];

    // Validate the file type
    $fileTypes = array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png'); // File extensions
    $fileParts = pathinfo($_FILES['Filedata']['name']);

    if (in_array($fileParts['extension'],$fileTypes)) {
        move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
        echo '1';
    } else {
        echo 'Invalid file type.';
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: http://www.leftandmain.com/silverstripe-tips/2011/02/15/uploadify-http-error-explained-and-solved-maybe/

Comment: it can't be that complicated... i want this to be included in a package that anyone can install, that would be a pain for whoever wants to use it.